# How to create a Salesforce Data Extensions?

Tags: marketing-cloud

How to create a Salesforce Data Extensions in Salesforce marketing Cloud?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer, it so simple.

Ref:
https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/marketing_cloud_connector_v5/features/salesforce_data_extensions/

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce Data Extensions can be imported through Interactions and Automation Studio:

> Import Salesforce data extensions into the Marketing Cloud through Interactions and Automation Studio. Create import activities with accessible Sales or Service Cloud reports. For example, reports in the Marketing Cloud Admin folder in the Sales or Service Cloud are not available for use if you don't have access to it in the Marketing Cloud.

For more information on Marketing Cloud Connect and Salesforce Data Extensions check out the following parts of the Marketing Cloud documentation:

- [Marketing Cloud Connect](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/marketing_cloud_connector_v5/)
- [Salesforce Data Extensions](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/marketing_cloud_connector_v5/features/salesforce_data_extensions/)

Comment: There is actually nothing (permissions aside) stopping someone from directly creating a Data Extension inside the Salesforce Data Extensions folder, or even moving a regular Data Extension into the Salesforce Data Extensions folder. The two directories are effectively the exact same, just the Salesforce one can push tracking data back into Salesforce when used correctly.